# Quadratic equation with natural number coefficients

Tags: quadratics, natural-numbers

Let $a,b,c $ be Natural Numbers, such that roots of the equation $ax^2-bx+c=0$ are distinct and both lie in the interval

1. (0,1)
2. (1,2)
3. (2,3)

(Brackets signify open interval, roots are  $IN BETWEEN $ the numbers in each part.)

Find minimum possible value of $a, b, c.$

On my part, I solved for part 1, i.e. for distinct roots between (0,1). But for the next two parts, the things are getting a too bit messy.

While it may have similarity in question for given part 1 in stack exchange, there is no generalized method so that we can solve for other such intervals.

So please help, I am new to stack exchange.

For part 3, I tried by taking $0<m-2, 3-m, n-2, 3-n <1$ where m, n are the roots of the equation, and then using A. M. - G. M method, but i failed.

Please check another question of this type, **But please don't provide with such answers as given in the link**, as this is a question of an entrance exam, to be solved by hand, and not wolfram mathematica.

[Consider the quadratic equation $ax^2-bx+c=0, a,b,c \in N. $ If the given equation has two distinct real root...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748229/consider-the-quadratic-equation-ax2-bxc-0-a-b-c-in-n-if-the-given-equati)

Please also tell me whether such numbers correspond to any famous known series.

**Many are telling that there can be no such coefficients, then for part 1, please check $5x^2-5x+1=0$. It has it's roots between 0 and 1, and the coefficients are natural numbers to be sure, namely** $a=5,b=5,c=1$.

Comment: I want to say that the roots are between, say for example, in between 2 and 3, and the equation has natural numbers as coefficients. Find the least  possible such natural number coefficients.

Comment: The midpoint between the roots is $\frac{b}{2a}$. Since the midpoint should be in the interval, that gives you two linear inequalitties. For example, for $(1,2)$ it gives $2a<b<4a$. The distance from the roots to their midpoint is $\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. This distance should be smaller than the distance from the midpoint to the endpoints of the interval. This gives two more linear inequalities. In the same example $\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}<\frac{b}{2a}-1$ gives $0<a+c-b$, and $\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}<2-\frac{b}{2a}$ gives $0<4a+c-4b$.

Comment: I tried all this, but without results. There are no bounds for any of the integral coefficient. I would like you to please provide the entire solution, I am just stuck.

Comment: The bounds come from the coefficients being natural numbers. Once you have one solution, there are a finite number of smaller possibilities.

Comment: Those are bounds on the coefficients. The locus where each inequality is an equality are planes. You can draw those planes in $3$-D Cartesian coordinates and pick those integer points in the first octant that lie inside the approprieate half-spaces.

Comment: The other thing is. If you have solved the first problem, then you have the solution for the other two. If $p(x)=0$ is one of those quadratics with its roots in $(0,1)$, then $p(x-1)$ has its roots in $(1,2)$. Likewise $p(x-2)$ has its roots in $(2,3)$.

Comment: @logarithm That is a neat observation. It doesn't find the minimum directly, but I think if it is possible to prove $a\gt 4$, this would be enough. It certainly finds a polynomial of the shape required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So multiply through by $4a$ to obtain $$4a^2x^2-4abx+4ac=(2ax-b)^2+4ac-b^2$$

Now with $a$ positive the quadratic has a minimum value at $x=\cfrac b{2a}$ and the value must be negative at this point so that $4ac-b^2\lt 0$. You also need $\cfrac b{2a}$ in the relevant range of values for $x$, and if the range is the interval $(p,q)$ you need the values at $p$ and $q$ to be positive.

The question is then about controlling for these conditions whilst keeping $a,b,c$ small.

---

So let's try it for the interval $(2,3)$

We need $4a-2b+c\gt 0$ and $9a-3b+c\gt 0$ from the conditions at the endpoints.

We also need $2\lt \frac b{2a}\lt 3$ ie $4a\lt b\lt 6a$

The smallest possible value of $a$ is $1$ which would make $b=5$ and we'd need $-6+c\gt 0$ ie $c\gt 6$

Now $4ac-b^2=4c-25$ must be negative and that is impossible for $c\gt 6$

So try $a=2$ with $b=9,10,11$

With $b=9$ we need$-10+c\gt 0$ and $-9+c\gt 0$ ie $c\gt 10$, and $8c-81\lt 0$ which is impossible for $c\gt 10$

With $b=10$ we get $c\gt 12$ and need $8c-100 \lt 0$ which is again impossible. But there is more margin here than with $a=1$ or with the asymmetric $b=9$.

Looking to be efficient, let's try for a symmetric solution with $a$ as small as possible and $b=5a$. We can the check other possibilities later.

The edge conditions are then $4a-10a+c\gt 0$ and $9a-15a+c\gt 0$ ie $c\gt 6a$
(or for later $4c\gt 24a$)

Then $4ac-b^2=4ac-25a^2\lt 0$ so that $25a\gt 4c\gt 24a$. So we need $a$ large enough that there is a multiple of $4$ between $24a$ (which is divisible by $4$) and $25a$. The least value of $a$ is $5$ and gives $b=25$ and $c=31$

I will leave you to do the extra checking. It is tedious going through the cases, but perfectly possible to do.

Note that (as suggested in comments) this is $5(x-2)^2-5(x-2)+1$

Comment: I know that, but that doesn't provide the answer, it is merely an equation

Comment: There can be more equation like taking the higher root less than upper bound, f(x) >0 at the two bounds and so on, but non provides the answer

Comment: @user10595795 I have added some workings to show what I intended. All the steps are straightforward. I have shown a polynomial for $(2,3)$ but left some work for you to do.

Comment: I must admit that you have done it quite correctly, but this is just one of the question among 54 other questions to be solved within 3 hours, namely jee advanced. Can you provide a solution which is less tedious and can be solved in such a time crunch?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

A quadratic polynomial $ax^2-bx+c \in\mathbf R[x]$ has distinct reals in the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ id and only if

1. It has two distinct roots, i.e. $\;b^2>4ac$
2. Neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ separate the roots, i.e. $\begin{cases}a\mkern1mu p(\alpha)>0,\\a\mkern1mup(\beta)>0.\end{cases}$
3. The arithmetic mean of the roots is in $(\alpha,\beta)$, which is equivalent to
   $$(b-2a\alpha)(b-2a\beta)<0.$$

Comment: This is something even i tried, but it literally provides nothing. I think i have provided what i tried in the comments and the question, kindly please read it.